# Jaws not able to read the aria-pressed="false". When I try to use down-arrow key

Tags: button, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have a button tag.

```
<button type="button" aria-label="Toolbar bold text" title="Bold" aria-pressed="false">
```

When I try to use JAWS to read the Bold button. Jaws is not able to read the aria-pressed state.

Comment: Is it reading the right role? Is it reading the pressed state when focusing the button by means of tab? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I have just tested now with Chrome and it works perfectly. The presence of the aria-pressed attribute automatically makes the button to be announced as toggle button, which is perfectly correct. Which browser and Jaws version are you using ?